# Viewing ESRI File GDB features without installing software

Tags: file-geodatabase, web-service, online-viewer

I'm looking for a way (Open source or otherwise) to view the contents and the features in a File GDB without installing any software locally.

Are the any current websites or web/map services or online viewrs that enable the uploading and viewing of a .gdb?

Again, I can obviously use QGIS or ArcGIS Explorer, but I need a solution for a local computer network that doesn't allow external installation, but does have internet access.

Comment: You can publish file geodatabase as a hosted service in ArcGIS Online if you have a subscription (can be done without having any software installed).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to ArcGIS Online, you may also use [MangoMap](https://mangomap.com/) to upload/publish/view gdb data (with monthly subscription).

Answer (score 0):

Use leafletjs filegdb
Works in browser no server needed
https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.filegdb

I use it as well as geopackage and vector tiles and shapefiles